# Avoiding default construction of elements in standard containers

Tags: c++, stl, initialization

I'm interested in building an `uninitialized_vector` container, which will be semantically identical to `std::vector` with the caveat that new elements which otherwise would be created with a no-argument constructor will instead be created without initialization. I'm primarily interested in avoiding initializing POD to 0. <strike>As far as I can tell, there's no way to accomplish this by combining `std::vector` with a special kind of allocator.</strike>

I'd like to build my container in the same vein as `std::stack`, which adapts a user-provided container (in my case, `std::vector`).  In other words, I'd like to avoid reimplementing the entirety of `std::vector` and instead provide a "facade" around it.

Is there a simple way to control default construction from the "outside" of `std::vector`?

---

Here's the solution I arrived at, which was inspired Kerrek's answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

// uninitialized_allocator adapts a given base allocator
// uninitialized_allocator's behavior is equivalent to the base
// except for its no-argument construct function, which is a no-op
template<typename T, typename BaseAllocator = std::allocator<T>>
  struct uninitialized_allocator
    : BaseAllocator::template rebind<T>::other
{
  typedef typename BaseAllocator::template rebind<T>::other super_t;

  template<typename U>
    struct rebind
  {
    typedef uninitialized_allocator<U, BaseAllocator> other;
  };

  // XXX for testing purposes
  typename super_t::pointer allocate(typename super_t::size_type n)
  {
    auto result = super_t::allocate(n);

    // fill result with 13 so we can check afterwards that
    // the result was not default-constructed
    std::fill(result, result + n, 13);
    return result;
  }

  // catch default-construction
  void construct(T *p)
  {
    // no-op
  }

  // forward everything else with at least one argument to the base
  template<typename Arg1, typename... Args>
    void construct(T* p, Arg1 &&arg1, Args&&... args)
  {
    super_t::construct(p, std::forward<Arg1>(arg1), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

namespace std
{

// XXX specialize allocator_traits
//     this shouldn't be necessary, but clang++ 2.7 + libc++ has trouble
//     recognizing that uninitialized_allocator<T> has a well-formed
//     construct function
template<typename T>
  struct allocator_traits<uninitialized_allocator<T> >
    : std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>
{
  typedef uninitialized_allocator<T> allocator_type;

  // for testing purposes, forward allocate through
  static typename allocator_type::pointer allocate(allocator_type &a, typename allocator_type::size_type n)
  {
    return a.allocate(n);
  }

  template<typename... Args>
    static void construct(allocator_type &a, T* ptr, Args&&... args)
  {
    a.construct(ptr, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
};

}

// uninitialized_vector is implemented by adapting an allocator and
// inheriting from std::vector
// a template alias would be another possiblity

// XXX does not compile with clang++ 2.9
//template<typename T, typename BaseAllocator>
//using uninitialized_vector = std::vector<T, uninitialized_allocator<T,BaseAllocator>>;

template<typename T, typename BaseAllocator = std::allocator<T>>
  struct uninitialized_vector
    : std::vector<T, uninitialized_allocator<T,BaseAllocator>>
{};

int main()
{
  uninitialized_vector<int> vec;
  vec.resize(10);

  // everything should be 13
  assert(std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 13) == vec.size());

  // copy construction should be preserved
  vec.push_back(7);
  assert(7 == vec.back());

  return 0;
}
```

This solution will work depending on how closely a particular vendor's compiler & STL's `std::vector` implementation conforms to c++11.

Comment: Can you just define a default constructor that does nothing? I bet the compiler may inline or omit it esp with optimization turned on.

Comment: @Doug T. - That may solve the case of the default constructor, but the interesting stuff seems to happen in ```resize``` -- it's unclear how to call functions like ```resize``` without invoking constructors.

Comment: @Doug: That has the caveat that you're no longer POD with a user-defined constructor...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem boils down to the type of initialization that the container performs on elements. Compare:

```
T * p1 = new T;   // default-initalization
T * p2 = new T(); // value-initialization
```

The problem with the standard containers is that they take the default argument to be value initialized, as in `resize(size_t, T = T())`. This means that there's no elegant way to avoid value-initialization or copying. (Similarly for the constructor.)

Even using the standard allocators doesn't work, because their central `construct()` function takes an argument that becomes value-initialized. What you would rather need is a `construct()` that uses default-initialization:

```
template <typename T>
void definit_construct(void * addr)
{
  new (addr) T;  // default-initialization
}
```

Such a thing wouldn't be a conforming standard allocator any more, but you could build your own container around that idea.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I don't understand your comment about ```construct()``` taking an argument that becomes value-initialized.  Why can't it be a no-op?

Comment: @Jared: I just mean the way that standard allocators are used in standard containers - their `construct()` function is usually something like `construct(void *, const T &)`, so there's at least one copy during construction, but I imagine that this function would be called with a value-initialized object anyway, like `construct(p, T())`, so you can't escape value initialization inside the standard containers. (Even the C++11 emplacing allocators can't help you because you cannot "move" something more than once...)

Comment: So basically I'm saying that you could rig up a container that behaves very much like `vector`, but instead of calling the standard allocator, you'd just make it say `new (addr) T;` instead of calling `construct()`. You can keep the other aspects of the allocator (i.e. memory allocation).

Comment: Interesting -- it looks like your ```resize(size_t, T = T())``` example actually isn't standard.  ```std::vector``` is required to distinguish between ```resize(size_t)``` and ```resize(size_t, const T &)``` (similarly for its constructors).  So it appears that a standard allocator may work, depending on how closely ```std::vector``` conforms.

Comment: By "standard" I meant of course [taken from a reliable source](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com) :-) Indeed, N3290 says that two distinct signatures `resize(size_t)` and `resize(size_t, const T &)` exist. So it's possible that `resize(n)` already behaves as you want.

Comment: The problem is that there are [three types of initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765961/default-value-and-zero-initialization-mess), but `std::allocator` only has two: zero and value.  There is no method for default initialization.  If there was, the containers could optionally use that instead.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a wrapper around the container, consider using a wrapper around the element type:

```
template <typename T>
struct uninitialized
{
    uninitialized() { }
    T value;
};
```

Comment: Doesn't that still default construct `value`?

Comment: Ah, didn't realise he was using only POD types.

Comment: I think something clever like this may work, but I have the additional requirements of preserving traits like ```std::vector::value_type```, ```std::vector::reference```, etc. These shouldn't expose ```unintialized<T>```.

Comment: Writing an `uninitialized_vector<T>` in terms of `vector<uninitialized<T>>` should be straightforward; each member function just needs to defer to the corresponding member function of the underlying `vector`, encapsulating access to `value` if required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible by wrapping a vector (that works with every type), unless you resize the vector on *every add and remove operation*.

If you could give up wrapping STL containers, you could do this by keeping an array of `char` on the heap and using placement `new` for each of the objects you want to construct. This way you could control exactly when the constructors and destructors of objects were called, one by one.