# Faster alternative to push_back(size is known)

Tags: c++, performance, vector, push-back

I have a float vector. As I process certain data, I push it back.I always know what the size will be while declaring the vector.

For the largest case, it is 172,490,752 floats. This takes about eleven seconds just to push_back everything.

Is there a faster alternative, like a different data structure or something?

Comment: [std::vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux this still takes like 6 seconds :( is this one of those things I'll just have to accept?

Comment: That's about 35 nano seconds per `push_back` (for 172,490,752). You *are* copying over a hundred million floats.

Comment: @anc What are you running this on, and are you running a release build? Even with an online compiler  such as [ideone](http://ideone.com/2XWATN) or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/437a79ad304caaf0), the numbers should be much better than six seconds. What *else* are you doing while pushing floats into a vector? (i.e. where are they coming from?).

Comment: might be a very stupid question so apologies but would adding a couple threads to do `push_back` help with speed? if the order doesn't matter?

Comment: @pyjg It wouldn't work. You would have race conditions all over

Comment: @Justin Yes thats why I said IF the order of insertion doesnt matter.

Comment: @pyjg The only way you could make that work is if you created the vector to the correct size and had the threads only access sections of the vector.

Comment: @pyjg `push_back` isn't atomic, so you  can get things much worse than out-of-order insertion

Comment: You enabled the optimizer?

Comment: @Justin could you please explain what all could go wrong? I thought if you do a `reserve` and add threads to `push_back` then yes the order is wrong but what else can happen that is bad? Thanks :)

Comment: @pyjg With 2 threads A and B. A and B call `V.push_back()` with `1` and `2` respectively. In A's perspective, `V.size() == 0`, so it inserts `1` into position `0`. In B's perspective, since it is executing at the same time as A, `V.size() == 0`, so it inserts `2` into position `0` (in reality, it could even be worse because different bytes might be written in and you might get a completely different number; depends on if writing a `float` is atomic). Meanwhile, A increments `V.size` and B does so too. After this, `V.size()` could be `1`, `2`, or something else, and `V[0]` is unknown as well

Comment: @pyjg Suppose `push_back` checks what the last element is, then assigns to it, then increments it. If you have multiple threads going at once you could get multiple assignments to the same address and/or skipped entries, and probably worse things are possible in a real implementation.

Comment: @anc Do you know the size of the vector at compile time, or only run time?

Comment: @Justin that makes a lot of sense, thank you

Comment: @DanielH thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @pyjg The basic problem is a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition). Once you are aware of the definition it's easier to spot them.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I knew it had to be a race condition but didnt realize exactly WHAT it would be. Thanks!

Comment: close match: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952412/performance-degradation-due-to-default-initialisation-of-elements-in-standard-co

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know the final size, then [reserve()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) that size after you declare the vector. That way it only has to allocate memory once.

Also, you may experiment with using [emplace_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) although I doubt it will make any difference for a vector of `float`. But try it and benchmark it (with an optimized build of course - you *are* using an optimized build - right?).

Another option when you know the size in advance is to use `std::array`.

Comment: `push_back` and `emplace_back` may still be slower than raw access because they have to check if there is need for reallocation, even if there isn't. The performance penalty may be slight, but it is there ;)

Comment: @Tobias maybe. Benchmarking the two solutions would be the way to tell.

Comment: I doubt `emplace_back` is any faster here, because floats are [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable)

Comment: @Daniel H: isn't that what I already said when I said "I doubt it will make any difference for a vector of float"? The fact that it is trivially copyable was sort of implied..

Comment: The implication is the other way around: because it is trivially copyable, there’s no difference between a copy and a move, so it won’t make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of speeding up a `vector` when you know the size beforehand is to call `reserve` on it before using `push_back`. This eliminates the overhead of reallocating memory and copying the data every time the previous capacity is filled.

Sometimes for very demanding applications this won't be enough. Even though `push_back` won't reallocate, it still needs to check the capacity every time. There's no way to know how bad this is without benchmarking, since modern processors are amazingly efficient when a branch is always/never taken.

You could try `resize` instead of `reserve` and use array indexing, but the `resize` forces a default initialization of every element; this is a waste if you know you're going to set a new value into every element anyway.

An alternative would be to use `std::unique_ptr<float[]>` and allocate the storage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[`::boost::container::stable_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.stable_vector) Notice that allocating a contiguous block of 172 *4 MB might easily fail and requires quite a lot page joggling. Stable vector is essentially a list of smaller vectors or arrays of reasonable size. You may also want to populate it in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I have two answers for you:

1. As previous answers have pointed out, using `reserve` to allocate the storage beforehand can be quite helpful, but:
2. `push_back` (or `emplace_back`) themselves have a performance penalty because during every call, they have to check whether the vector has to be reallocated. If you know the number of elements you will insert already, you can avoid this penalty by directly setting the elements using the access operator `[]`

So the most efficient way I would recommend is:

1. Initialize the vector with the 'fill'-constructor:

   ```
   std::vector<float> values(172490752, 0.0f);
   ```
2. Set the entries directly using the access operator:

   ```
   values[i] = some_float;
   ++i;
   ```

Comment: This would require benchmarks; it's totally possible that this would be *slower*, as the vector would have to initialize every element, then overwrite it later.

Comment: If it were possible to initialize the storage without filling the vector explicitly, this would probably be the fastest solution ;) I'll check the assembly output first

Comment: @Tobias How would you initialize the storage without filling it? Do you mean allocating the storage without filling it?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think he means that if `std::vector::resize` didn't default initialize, for instance. Basically if it behaved like `reserve` but the length of the vector was also set to be the length of the capacity.

Comment: @Justin Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I doubt there’s a way that does that for all types, but it would be nice if there were a method to [default initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) a bunch of elements instead of initializing them to a specific value; for `float`s that would be a no-op. It looks like allocators in general don’t have that option, though, so it’s no wonder `vector` doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom allocator which avoids default initialisation of all elements, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15966795/1023390), in conjunction with ordinary element access:

```
const size_t N = 172490752;
std::vector<float, uninitialised_allocator<float> > vec(N);
for(size_t i=0; i!=N; ++i)
    vec[i] = the_value_for(i);
```

This avoids (i) default initializing all elements, (ii) checking for capacity at every push, and (iii) reallocation, but at the same time preserves all the convenience of using `std::vector` (rather than `std::unique_ptr<float[]>`). However, the `allocator` template parameter is unusual, so you will need to use generic code rather than `std::vector`-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `push_back` is slow is that it will need to copy all the data several times as the vector grows, and even when it doesn’t need to copy data it needs to check. Vectors grow quickly enough that this doesn’t happen often, but it still does happen. A rough rule of thumb is that every element will need to be copied on average once or twice; the earlier elements will need to be copied a lot more, but almost half the elements won’t need to be copied at all.

You can avoid the copying, but not the checks, by calling `reserve` on the vector when you create it, ensuring it has enough space. You can avoid both the copying and the checks by creating it with the right size from the beginning, by giving the number of elements to the vector constructor, and then inserting using indexing as [Tobias suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44934428/27302); unfortunately, this also goes through the vector an extra time initializing everything.

If you know the number of floats at compile time and not just runtime, you could use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), which avoids all these problems. If you only know the number at runtime, I would second [Mark’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935063/27302) to go with [`std::unique_ptr<float[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). You would create it with

```
size_t size = /* Number of floats */;
auto floats = unique_ptr<float[]>{new float[size]};
```

You don’t need to do anything special to delete this; when it goes out of scope it will free the memory. In most respects you can use it like a vector, but it won’t automatically resize.