# Why does C++ multiplication with dynamic array work better than std::vector version

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, matrix, openmp

I am implementing the C++ multiplication for matrices with different data structures and techniques (vectors , arrays and OpenMP) and I found a strange situation... My dynamic array version is working better:

times:

> openmp mult_1: time: 5.882000 s
>
> array mult_2: time: 1.478000 s

My compilation flags are:

> /usr/bin/g++    -fopenmp -pthread -std=c++1y -O3

**C++ vector version**

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<float>> matrix_f;
void mult_1 (const matrix_f &  matrixOne, const matrix_f & matrixTwo, matrix_f & result) {
    const int matrixSize = (int)result.size();
    #pragma omp parallel for simd
    for (int rowResult = 0; rowResult < matrixSize; ++rowResult) {
        for (int colResult = 0; colResult < matrixSize; ++colResult) {
            for (int k = 0; k < matrixSize; ++k) {
                result[rowResult][colResult] += matrixOne[rowResult][k] * matrixTwo[k][colResult];  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dynamic array version**

```
void mult_2 ( float *  matrixOne, float * matrixTwo,  float * result, int size)  {
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
                (*(result+(size*row)+col)) += (*(matrixOne+(size*row)+k)) * (*(matrixTwo+(size*k)+col));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tests:

**C++ vector version**

```
utils::ChronoTimer timer;
/* set Up simple matrix */
utils::matrix::matrix_f matr1 = std::vector<std::vector<float>>(size,std::vector<float>(size));
fillRandomMatrix(matr1);

utils::matrix::matrix_f matr2 = std::vector<std::vector<float>>(size,std::vector<float>(size));
fillRandomMatrix(matr2);

utils::matrix::matrix_f result = std::vector<std::vector<float>>(size,std::vector<float>(size));    
timer.init();
utils::matrix::mult_1(matr1,matr2,result);
std::printf("openmp mult_1: time: %f ms\n",timer.now() / 1000);
```

**Dynamic array version**

```
utils::ChronoTimer timer;

float *p_matr1 = new float[size*size];
float *p_matr2 = new float[size*size];
float *p_result = new float[size*size];

fillRandomMatrixArray(p_matr1,size);
fillRandomMatrixArray(p_matr2,size);

timer.init();
utils::matrix::mult_2(p_matr1,p_matr2,p_result,size);
std::printf("array mult_2: time: %f ms\n",timer.now() / 1000);

delete [] p_matr1;
delete [] p_matr2;
delete [] p_result;
```

I was checking some previous posts, but I couldn't find any related with my problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381621/using-arrays-or-stdvectors-in-c-whats-the-performance-gap), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446684/vector-vs-array-performance), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664272/is-stdvector-so-much-slower-than-plain-arrays):

**UPDATE:**
I refactorized tests with the answers, and vector works slighty better :

> vector mult: time: 1.194000 s
>
> array mult_2: time: 1.202000 s

**C++ vector version**

```
void mult (const std::vector<float> &  matrixOne, const std::vector<float> & matrixTwo, std::vector<float> & result, int size) {
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
            for (int k = 0; k <size; ++k) {
                result[(size*row)+col] += matrixOne[(size*row)+k] * matrixTwo[(size*k)+col];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Dynamic array version**

```
void mult_2 ( float *  matrixOne, float * matrixTwo,  float * result, int size)  {
    for (int row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
            for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) {
                (*(result+(size*row)+col)) += (*(matrixOne+(size*row)+k)) * (*(matrixTwo+(size*k)+col));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, my vectorized version is working better(0.803 s);

Comment: The data is arranged differently in memory. You're matricies are contiguous in memory while doing `vector<vector>` allocates each vector seperately. If the size is fixed at compile-time you could try `vector<array<float,N>>` or do something else to make sure that the complete matrix is contiguous in memory.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259877/1d-or-2d-array-whats-faster on why you would generally want to avoid "real" 2d structures (like `T**`, `vector<vector<T>>` ...) for storing dense matrices.

Comment: I going to guess memory layout is not your only issue. Show us your timer code and how many threads you are running the openmp version on.

Comment: @jepio I am applying each improvement step by step... I change the allocation error, I check the threads and I post the thread configuration

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A vector of vectors is analogous to a jagged array -- an array where each entry is a pointer, each pointer pointing at another array of floats.

In comparison, the raw array version is one block of memory, where you do math to find the elements.

Use a single vector, not a vector of vectors, and do the math manually.  Or, use a vector of fix-sized `std::array`s.  Or write a helper type that takes the (one-dimensional) vector of float, and gives you a 2 dimensional view of it.

Data in a contiguous buffer is more cache and optimization friendly than data in a bunch of disconnected buffers.

```
template<std::size_t Dim, class T>
struct multi_dim_array_view_helper {
  std::size_t const* dims;
  T* t;
  std::size_t stride() const {
    return
      multi_dim_array_view_helper<Dim-1, T>{dims+1, nullptr}.stride()
      * *dims;
  }
  multi_dim_array_view_helper<Dim-1, T> operator[](std::size_t i)const{
    return {dims+1, t+i*stride()};
  }
};
template<class T>
struct multi_dim_array_view_helper<1, T> {
  std::size_t stride() const{ return 1; }
  T* t;
  T& operator[](std::size_t i)const{
    return t[i];
  }
  multi_dim_array_view_helper( std::size_t const*, T* p ):t(p) {}
};
template<std::size_t Dims>
using dims_t = std::array<std::size_t, Dims-1>;
template<std::size_t Dims, class T>
struct multi_dim_array_view_storage
{
  dims_t<Dims> storage;
};
template<std::size_t Dims, class T>
struct multi_dim_array_view:
  multi_dim_array_view_storage<Dims, T>,
  multi_dim_array_view_helper<Dims, T>
{
  multi_dim_array_view( dims_t<Dims> d, T* t ):
    multi_dim_array_view_storage<Dims, T>{std::move(d)},
    multi_dim_array_view_helper<Dims, T>{
      this->storage.data(), t
    }
  {}
};
```

now you can do this:

```
std::vector<float> blah = {
   01.f, 02.f, 03.f,
   11.f, 12.f, 13.f,
   21.f, 22.f, 23.f,
};

multi_dim_array_view<2, float> view = { {3}, blah.data() };
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
{
  std::cout << "[";
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j )
    std::cout << view[i][j] << ",";
  std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c037d5fe245474c)

No data is copied in the view class.  It just provides a view of the flat array that is a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

Your approaches are quite different:

- In the "dynamic array" version you allocate a single chunk of memory for each matrix and map the rows of the matrices onto that one dimensional memory range.
- In the "vector" version you use vectors of vectors which are "real" and "dynamically" two dimensional meaning that the storage position of each row of your matrices is unrelated with respect to the other rows.

What you probably want to do is:

- Use `vector<float>(size*size)` and perform the very same mapping you're doing in the "dynamic array" example by hand or
- Write a class that internally handles the mapping for you and provides a 2-dimensional access interface (`T& operator()(size_t, size_t)` or some kind of `row_proxy operator[](size_t)` where `row_proxy` in turn has `T& operator[](size_t)`)

Answer (score 1):

This is just to enforce the theory (in practice) about the contiguous memory.

After doing some analysis on the code generated with g++ (-O2) the source can be found at: https://gist.github.com/42be237af8e3e2b1ca03

The relevant code generated for the array version is:

```
.L3:
    lea r9, [r13+0+rbx]                ; <-------- KEEPS THE ADDRESS
    lea r11, [r12+rbx]
    xor edx, edx
.L7:
    lea r8, [rsi+rdx]
    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [r9]
    xor eax, eax
.L6:
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r11+rax*4]
    add rax, 1
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r8]
    add r8, r10
    cmp ecx, eax
    addss   xmm1, xmm0
    movss   DWORD PTR [r9], xmm1     ; <------------ ADDRESS IS USED
    jg  .L6
    add rdx, 4
    add r9, 4                        ; <--- ADDRESS INCREMENTED WITH SIZE OF FLOAT
    cmp rdx, rdi
    jne .L7
    add ebp, 1
    add rbx, r10
    cmp ebp, ecx
    jne .L3
```

see how usage of the value of `r9` is reflecting the contiguous memory for the destination array and `r8` for one of the input arrays.

On the other end, the vector of vectors generates code like:

```
.L12:
    mov r9, QWORD PTR [r12+r11]
    mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rbx+r11]
    xor ecx, ecx
.L16:
    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rdi+rcx]
    mov rdx, r10
    xor eax, eax
    jmp .L15
.L13:
    movaps  xmm1, xmm0
.L15:
    mov rsi, QWORD PTR [rdx]
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax]
    add rax, 4
    add rdx, 24
    cmp r8, rax
    mulss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi+rcx]
    addss   xmm0, xmm1
    movss   DWORD PTR [rdi+rcx], xmm0   ; <------------ HERE
    jne .L13
    add rcx, 4
    cmp rcx, r8
    jne .L16
    add r11, 24
    cmp r11, rbp
    jne .L12
```

Not surprisingly, the compiler is clever enough to not to generate code for all the `operator []` calls, and does a good job of inlining them, but see how it needs to track different addresses via `rdi + rcx` when it stores the value back to the result vector, and also the extra memory accesses for the various sub-vectors (`mov   rsi, QWORD PTR [rdx]`) which all generate some overhead.