# Double (two-dimensional) array using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a double array allocated by pointer to pointer.

```
  // pointer to pointer
  int **x = new int *[5];   // allocation
  for (i=0; i<5; i++){
      x[i] = new int[2];
  }

  for (i=0; i<5; i++){      // assignment
      for (j=0; j<2; j++){
          x[i][j] = i+j;
      }
  }

  for (i=0; i<5; i++)   // deallocation
      delete x[i];
  delete x;
```

I am trying to do this using `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int>[]> a(new std::unique_ptr<int>[5]);
  for (i=0; i<5; i++)
      a[i] = new int[2];
```

but kept getting an error saying that `no operator = matches these operands`. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 25):

You cannot assign a `int*` to a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`, that is the cause for your error.  The correct code is

```
      a[i] = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[2]);
```

However, piokuc is correct, that it is highly unusual to use `unique_ptr` for arrays, as that's what `std::vector` and `std::array` are for, depending on if the size is known ahead of time.

```
//make a 5x2 dynamic jagged array, 100% resizable any time
std::vector<std::vector<int>> container1(5, std::vector<int>(2)); 
//make a 5x2 dynamic rectangular array, can resize the 5 but not the 2
std::vector<std::array<int, 2>> container1(5); 
//make a 5x2 automatic array, can't resize the 2 or 5 but is _really fast_.
std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 5> container;
```

All of these can be initialized and used just the same as the code you already had, except they're easier to construct, and you don't have to destroy them.

Comment: Of course, `std::unique_ptr<int>(new int[2]);` will have the wrong deleter -- that should be `std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[2]);`. Preemptive +1 assuming you'll fix that. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I've never used `unique_ptr` of arrays, I'm fuzzy on the syntax.  Thanks!

Comment: @Evan: Be sure to upvote any answers you found helpful (with the up arrow on the left), and mark one as the "correct" answer (with the check-mark just under the arrows).

Answer (score 8):

If you do not have the luxury of using a `std::array` or a `std::vector` instead of a dynamically allocated array, you can use a `std::unique_ptr` for a two-dimensional array in C++11 as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<int*, std::function<void(int**)>> x(
    new int*[10](),
    [](int** x) {
        std::for_each(x, x + 10, std::default_delete<int[]>());
        delete[] x;
    }
);
```

The `unique_ptr` declaration takes care of allocating the *row* dimension of the array. The trailing `()` in `new int*[10]()` ensures that each column pointer is initialized to `nullptr`.

A for loop then allocates the column arrays:

```
for (size_t row = 0; row < 10; ++row) {
    (x.get())[row] = new int[5];
}
```

When the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, its custom deleter lambda function takes care of deleting the column arrays before deleting the row array. The `for_each` expression uses the [default_delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) functor.

Comment: Could this be extended using `_mm_malloc` and how?

Comment: Use `__mm_malloc` to allocate the memory and use `_mm_free` in the custom deleter.

Comment: Thanks, I got this working. Forgot your second piece, i.e. to allocate the individual rows (without this, I got a segmentation fault). Working on an example using variadic templates, where I can create multi-dimensional arrays, without accessing data using `.get()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)   // deallocation
      delete x[i];
  delete x;
```

NO NO NO NO

```
delete [] x[i];
delete [] x;
```

// yo

Answer (score 2):

Your code is effectively manipulating an array of arrays of int.

In C++ you would normally want to implement it as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > x;
```

This is not a good case for `unique_ptr`. Also, you should not need to use pointers to `unique_ptr` and allocate `unique_ptr` objects dynamically. The whole point of `unique_ptr` is to eliminate usage of pointers and to provide automatic allocation and deallocation of objects.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. The way I understand unique_ptr is that it ensures that the instance it points to only has 1 reference. So using unique_ptr to point to an unique_ptr to create a matrix should be fine to use unique_ptr, given that there won't be another reference to the instance. Also, I don't understand the reason behind the last sentence. Thanks.

Comment: any RAII class should offer that same unique guarantee.  Most C++ classes are RAII.  So you should use the right tool for the job.  vector and array should be preferred to unique_ptr here.

Comment: the reason for unique ptrs is mostly to hold dynamically allocated single objects.  I can't immediately think of a reason to store an array in a unique_ptr.

Comment: There are some good use cases for it (surely!) since it is catered for specifically within the standard: the primary template `unique_ptr< T >` and specialisation `unique_ptr< T[] >`.

I'm guessing it's not just for completeness since there is no such specialisation for `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The only reasons I can think of to use std::unique_ptr (or say boost::scoped_array) over std::vector for holding arrays are usually not applicable...

1) it saves 1 or 2 pointers worth of memory, depending on if you know what the size of all the arrays is [irrelevant unless you have a massive number of very small arrays]

2) in case you are just passing the array into some function that expects a C style array or raw pointer, it may feel like a more natural fit. std::vector IS guaranteed to be on sequential storage though, so passing `(a.empty() ? nullptr : &a[0], a.size())` into such a function is 100% legit as well.

3) standard containers in MSVC debug mode are "checked" by default and very slow, which might be annoying when doing scientific programming on large datasets.

Comment: An advantage of unique_ptr<int[]> over vector<int> is that you can avoid initialization, the cost of which may be significant in some cases.  Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96579/stl-vectors-with-uninitialized-storage and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546620/operator-new-initializes-memory-to-zero

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#define print(x) std::cout << x
#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<int[]>[]> arr(new std::unique_ptr<int[]>[2]());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = std::make_unique<int[]>(5);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = j;
            println(arr[i][j]);
        }
        println(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "#define println(x) std::cout << x << std::endl", this is what println() !

Comment: @Blastfurnace and for the rest, i asked the same question and they give me this solution and it worked so i thought it'll be helpful :)

Comment: @Blastfurnace i've edited the code, is it good now?

Answer (score 0):

An example further up inspired me for this solution

```
size_t k = 10;
std::unique_ptr<int*, std::function<void(int**)>> y(new int*[k](),
    [](int** x) {delete [] &(x[0][0]);
                 delete[] x;});

// Allocate the large array
y.get()[0] = new int[k*10];

// Establish row-pointers
for (size_t row = 0; row < k; ++row) {
  (y.get())[row] = &(y.get()[0][0]);
}
```

Here all dimensions can be dynamic and you can wrap it inside a class and expose an operator[]. Also the memory is allocated in a contiguous manner and you can easily introduce an allocator, which allocates aligned memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)   // deallocation
      delete x[i];
delete x;
```

It is a common mistake here.
x[i] is an array so you have to delete each array first using delete[]
Then you can delete you array of int* by using delete[]

Correct desallocation would be:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)   
      delete[] x[i]; //desallocate each array of int
delete[] x; //desallocate your array of int*
x = nullptr; //good practice to be sure it wont cause any dmg
```